# Use aggreagted row values in multiple columns to form new column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe in which each record has either D or E filled. Never both.
The following is the dataframe df, with dummy records for 2 months April(Current) & March. (Originally the data will have 12 months, with values for column B reoccurring )

[image]

I am looking to:
1. groupby column A for ***April month*** sum(column D) / sum(column E)

[image]

```
df.groupby(['A', 'C']).df.D/df.E.sum().rolling(1, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Alternatively tried,

```
def divide_two_cols(df):
    return df['D'].sum() / df['E'].sum()

df.groupby(['A', 'C']).divide_two_cols(df).sum().rolling(1, min_periods=1).sum()
```

2. Apply same to last two months (***March & April***)

[image]

```
df.groupby(['A', 'C']).df.D/df.E.sum().rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Any advise on why the either approach is not working to form a new column using sum of two other columns.

Comment: Will your data always have only 2 months or could have more months and you are going to calculate it only for the latest two? I think this is not very clear. It's best you specify everything explicitly

Comment: Edited my question accordingly, Thanks. @frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to group by at month level, you should ideally try to extract the month from column C which will make things easier for you.

```
df['F'] = df.C.apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[1])

print(df)
   A      C     D    E    F
0  W  6-Mar   NaN  1.0  Mar
1  W  6-Mar   4.0  NaN  Mar
2  W  6-Mar   NaN  1.0  Mar
3  W  6-Apr   2.0  NaN  Apr
4  W  6-Apr   NaN  2.0  Apr
5  Y  6-Mar  10.0  NaN  Mar
6  Y  6-Mar   NaN  2.0  Mar
7  Y  6-Apr   6.0  NaN  Apr
8  Y  6-Apr   NaN  2.0  Apr
```

For Part 1 (Column G is the column you are looking for):

```
df_grouped1 = df.groupby(['A', 'F'])['D', 'E'].sum().reset_index()
df_grouped1['G'] = df_grouped1['D']/df_grouped1['E']

print(df_grouped1)
    A   F    D     E     G
0   W   Apr  2.0  2.0   1.0
1   W   Mar  4.0  2.0   2.0
2   Y   Apr  6.0  2.0   3.0
3   Y   Mar 10.0  2.0   5.0
```

For Part 2 (Not sure if I understood this part of the question correctly. Correct me if I am wrong) :

```
print(df_grouped1.groupby('A')['G'].mean().reset_index())

   A    G
0  W  1.5
1  Y  4.0
```

Comment: I was able to formulate Part 2 (for last 12 months) from your solution to part one;
 ```df_grouped1 = df.groupby(['A', 'F'])['D', 'E'].sum().rolling(12, min_periods=1).sum()
df_grouped1['G'] = df_grouped1['D']/df_grouped1['E']```